# Made an AJAX function but jQuery doesn't seem to respond to it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I built a pretty basic dynamic AJAX function to load in content onto the current page using jQuery.

I tested it on a pretty generic page and got it working without a hitch, however as soon as I put this code into the actual production site I wanted it for it just doesn't work.

I've tried every which way to get this to work, so I'm not sure what else to do now. I have a niggling feeling that I've used the wrong selectors in the production site. Although that is probably just from a lack of confidence (beginner) I actually think that the jQuery just isn't working at all.

Here's the code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function(){
        var a = $('article.announce');
        var s = $('#info li a');
        // You only need to change the above two pieces of code.    

            s.click(function(){
                var url = $(this).html(),
                    clicked = $(this).attr('data-id');



                    $(s+'[data-id='+clicked+']').click(function(){
                        a.load(url+'.html')


                    }); 
}); 
});</script>
```

The HTML I'm trying to target is as follows:

```
    <aside id="info" class="clearfix">
<h1>About Us &gt;</h1>
<h2>Other Stuff:</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="1">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="2">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="3">Examples</a></li>

</ul>



</aside>
<article class="announce">
<p>Text to be replaced will be here!</p>




</article>
```

Hopefully I've given you enough information to see what's wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the HTML markup:

```
<aside id="info" class="clearfix">
    <h1>About Us &gt;</h1>
    <h2>Other Stuff:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="example.html">Examples</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>

<article class="announce">
    <p>Text to be replaced will be here!</p>
</article>
```

Then do this:

```
$(function() {
    var a = $('.announce');
    $('#info li a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        a.load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(s+'[data-id='+clicked+']').click(function(){ 
                        a.load(url+'.html') 
                     });
```

s is object here but it should be string and **place it outside the s.click function**

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand that, as it worked perfectly when I created the function. Why would it work on one site then not on the other?

Comment: No they aren't. I really think that my document isn't loading jQuery properly as I tried a few basic things such as changing an elements color to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

you are using click inside click try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = $('article.announce');
   var s = $('#info li a');
   s.click(function(){
        var url = $(this).html();
        a.load(url+'.html')
      }); 
});
```

make sure the first lettre of you html file are in uppercase

Comment: Hey man as I mentioned I am a bit of a beginner, I used the original click event to store the information I needed to variables url and clicked for the second click event which was to deal with the actual locating and loading of the other page. Thanks for the heads up on the capitalizing, I did already do that but almost missed it a few days ago when I first wrote the code :P

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/83V4K/

You only need 1 click event.

```
var a = $('article.announce');
var s = $('#info li a');

s.click(function(){
    var url = $(this).
    a.load(url+'.html');
}); ​
```

Comment: This didn't work, I'm not sure I adequately explained what I was trying to do though so thanks anyway!